# Magento dynamic block adding contents

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento CMS, i have configured products using admin panel, at the home page

1. I want to list down random famous
   products from different categories
   dynamically.
2. When i list the products they appear
   in the menu by their categories,
   when i chose page type 3 columns
   where are the source files for
   column 1 and 3 how can i
   change/configure them.
3. I installed Magento with sample data
   from home page when i click upon any
   item it does not display data.
4. I see default home page using
   dynamic contents block from where to
   create it and how to see it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to split questions into individuals one, in order to get more accurate answers. Anyway:
1. [Yoast Landing Pages](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yoast/extension/1915/yoast-landing-pages) allows you to create products listings of any attribute you want
2. I'm not sure to understand you, but I think what you're looking for is in `app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/layout/catalog.xml`. Inside `<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">` add/modify `<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>`
3. It seems you don't have mod_rewrite enabled in your server
4. If you're using Magento's sampla data, it is not dynamic content: check in your admin CMS -> Pages -> (Title) Home Page

Answer (score 0):

Strategy for you:

1. make a new extension with a block and a layout file
2. have your layout file define the block output and use the product list template and your block
3. in your block make a query to magento popular products report to get the popular stuff you need
4. design the hell out of it and $$$$